# How to use the APARM, BPARM and CPARM of REGRD task in AIPS?

Tags: radio-astronomy, image-processing

I plan to regrid a 500 by 500 image in B1950 to 500 by 500 in J2000 using the AIPS task REGRD. How to proceed?

Comment: Such a short and open-ended question will often not receive a helpful answer until more detail is added. The problem is that people who may want to write an answer might spend a lot of time assuming you have some set of skills, and then there's a comment something like "I know that already, but I'm having problems with..." To be more helpful, can you explain a little more what it is that is stopping you from understanding all documentation that's available, what you have tried already, what didn't work, what error messages you may have received, etc.

Comment: I apologise. Before your reply I had already decided to see for myself what happened if I proceeded and experimented with the information provided in the documentation and found out a way. I was so engrossed that I did not read your comments until now.

Comment: Oh, that's great news! If you think that you can add some helpful information then it's perfectly fine in Stack Exchange to post answers to your own question, and in a day or two if there are no further answers, to accept it as well.